# SQlite: insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I've been looking at the code below for God knows how long and I can't seem to find what the issue is. Most discussions I've seen on in relation to the stated error indicate that the source is from typos of the parameters. But why lie, I can't see any typo. Can someone tell me where am going wrong?

```
Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable
dim sqlText as string
sqlText = "SELECT id AS privilegeID, " & _
"user_id AS userID, " & _
"module_id AS moduleID, " & _
"can_read AS canRead, " & _
"can_create AS canCreate, " & _
"can_update AS canUpdate, " & _
"can_delete AS canDelete, " & _
"is_deleted AS isDeleted, " & _
"is_active AS isActive " & _
"FROM base_user_privilege " & _
"WHERE " & _
"user_id=@userID AND " & _
"is_deleted=@isDeleted AND " & _
"is_active=@isActive"
SetDBCommand(sqlText)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isDeleted", IsDeleted)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", IsActive)
dt = DBAction(sqlText, DBActionType.DataTable)
```

The **setdbcommand(sqltext)** is meant to establish the connection and it works so I don't think the error is there as its working on other select and insert statements.

Please assist.

Thanks.

**EDITS**

Here is the setdbcommand:

```
Public Sub SetDBCommand(ByVal sqlString As String)
    If DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        DBConnection.Open()
    End If
    DBCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sqlString, DBConnection)
End Sub
```

**Works in Reader but not data Table**

I've realized that with my dataconnection function, the above parameters work when passed via the **DataReader** but don't work when passed via the **DataTable** Is there something am missing? Do parameters work with DataTables?

```
Public Function DBAction(ByVal sqlText As String, ByVal ActionType As DBActionType) As Object
    DBAction = Nothing
    Select Case ActionType
        Case DBActionType.DataReader
            Return DBCommand.ExecuteReader
        Case DBActionType.Dataset
            Dim MyAdpater As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlText, DBConnection)
            Dim myDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet
            MyAdpater.Fill(myDataSet)
            Return myDataSet
        Case DBActionType.DataTable
            Dim MyAdpater As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlText, DBConnection)
            Dim MyDataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
            MyAdpater.Fill(MyDataTable)
            Return MyDataTable
        Case DBActionType.executeNonQuery
            DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Case DBActionType.ExecuteScalar
            Dim ScalarItem As Object = DBCommand.ExecuteScalar
            Return ScalarItem
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Error in DBACTION")
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: please include SetDBcommand for context. Can't see what's going on without it!

Comment: I've added the setdbcommand function.

Comment: What happens if you replace `@parameter` with `:parameter`? Or try changing the parameter names all together (you have the parameter names the same as aliased columns...that shouldn't be an issue, but "shouldn't" and "isn't" can often be different in debugging...)

Comment: I've replaced the `@parameter` with `:parameter` but its still gives me the same error. I've also changed the parameter names and still I get the same error.

Comment: why are you initializing `MyAdapter` with `sqlText`, and not using the command at all?  How does the adapter use the parameters this way?

Comment: The logic is such that the `setdbcommand` initializes the Command as shown in the SetDBCommand routine. The next 3 lines add the parameters for the command. Then, the `DBAction Function` is called to fill the datatable. It has always worked with the reader so I thought/assumed It'd work the same for the datatabe. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: It makes sense that it works with the `DataReader`, since you're calling `DBCommand.ExecuteReader`.  With `DataSet` and `DataTable`, however, you are just supplying the text for the sql...the DBCommand never gets referenced, so the setup work is moot.  I believe SQLiteDataAdapter will either let you provide DBCommand instead of string, or else you can set the MyAdapter.SelectCommand (or similar) to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: What!??? Its worked. Thank @sybkar Yes, the `Myadapter` was initialized all wrong... I've now put `Dim MyAdpater As New SQLiteDataAdapter(DBCommand)` and it has worked. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBCommand must be supplied as a parameter when creating the SQLiteDataAdapter.  As a bonus, you won't need to provide the connection parameter, since you've already setup the command appropriately:

```
Public Function DBAction(ByVal sqlText As String, ByVal ActionType As DBActionType) As Object
    DBAction = Nothing
    Select Case ActionType
        Case DBActionType.DataReader
            Return DBCommand.ExecuteReader
        Case DBActionType.Dataset
            Dim MyAdpater As New SQLiteDataAdapter(DBCommand)
            Dim myDataSet As New System.Data.DataSet
            MyAdpater.Fill(myDataSet)
            Return myDataSet
        Case DBActionType.DataTable
            Dim MyAdpater As New SQLiteDataAdapter(DBCommand)
            Dim MyDataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
            MyAdpater.Fill(MyDataTable)
            Return MyDataTable
        Case DBActionType.executeNonQuery
            DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Case DBActionType.ExecuteScalar
            Dim ScalarItem As Object = DBCommand.ExecuteScalar
            Return ScalarItem
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Error in DBACTION")
    End Select
End Function
```

As an aside, since I didn't see them anywhere in the code you posted, make sure you're properly disposing of the `SQLiteCommand` and `SQLiteDataAdapter` objects.  The connection should be closed, and then disposed, when finished.

Comment: If you do it this way you don't even need sqlText parameter. I still would encourage passing in the command instead of using a global though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are adding your parameters to DBCommand but in the case statement your adapter never uses DBCommand it only gets the string you passed in (sqlText).

One possible solution is to instead of passing sqlText in as a parameter pass the whole command in and assign it to your MyAdapter.SelectCommand

```
Function DBAction( inCommand As SQLiteCommand, ActionType As DBActionType)
```